# Floyd's cycle detection algorithm in linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, interview-questions

I am doing interview studying and would like to have another look at my implementation of Floyd's cycle detection algorithm.

I've implemented a simple linked list which can be fluently configured and works generally for any type on stack. The cycle detection method serves:

- to find if there are any cycles in list or return Optional.empty()
- to return the start node value of the cycle, if there is any

A cycle should be found in worst-case O(n) time complexity and O(1) space consumption. The same applies for retrieving the cycle start node.

Apart from correctness, I've strived for client simplicity, null-safety and clarity - would like to hear thoughts on how to improve this code and/or add more test cases.

Here is the data structure:

```
public class CyclicLinkedList<T> {

private Builder.Node<T> first;
private int count = 0;

private CyclicLinkedList() {}

public static <T> AddNext<T> builder() {
    return new CyclicLinkedList.Builder<>();
}

public Optional<T> firstNodeInCycle() {
    if (count < 2) return Optional.empty();
    Builder.Node<T> slow = first;
    Builder.Node<T> fast = first;

    while (true) {
        if (fast == null) return Optional.empty(); // if fast reaches end, no cycle
        fast = fast.next; // advance fast one more step
        if (fast == null) return Optional.empty(); // again check if fast reached end - if it does, no cycle
        fast = fast.next; // advance both one step
        slow = slow.next;
        if (fast.index == slow.index) { // if fast and slow are equal, that can only mean fast has reached slow from behind, thus proving cycle
            slow = first;
            while (true) { // find the starting point of the cycle
                if (fast.index == slow.index) return Optional.of(slow.item);
                slow = slow.next;
                fast = fast.next;
            }
        }
    }
}

private boolean isEmpty() {
    return count == 0;
}

public interface AddNext<T> {
    AddNext<T> addNext(T item);

    Build<T> defineCycleOrBuild();
}

public interface Build<T> {
    Build<T> connectLastTo(int index);

    CyclicLinkedList<T> build();
}

private static class Builder<T> implements AddNext<T>, Build<T> {
    private CyclicLinkedList<T> instance = new CyclicLinkedList<>();

    private static class Node<Item> {
        private final int index;
        private final Item item;
        private Node<Item> next;

        private Node(int idx, Item nestedItem, Node<Item> nextNode) {
            index = idx;
            item = nestedItem;
            next = nextNode;
        }

        private static <V> Node<V> firstNodeOf(V item) {
            return new Node<>(0, item, null);
        }

        private static <V> Node<V> nextNodeOf(V item, Node<V> nextNode) {
            return new Node<>(nextNode.index + 1, item, nextNode);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public AddNext<T> addNext(T item) {
        Node<T> oldFirst = instance.first;

        if (instance.isEmpty())
            instance.first = Node.firstNodeOf(item);
        else
            instance.first = Node.nextNodeOf(item, oldFirst);
        instance.count++;

        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public Build<T> defineCycleOrBuild() {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public Build<T> connectLastTo(int index) {
        if (instance.isEmpty()) throw new IllegalStateException("Stack underflow");
        Node<T> node = findAt(index);
        Node<T> last = findLast();
        last.next = node;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public CyclicLinkedList<T> build() {
        return instance;
    }

    private Node<T> findAt(int index) {
        for (Node<T> x = instance.first; x != null; x = x.next)
            if (x.index == index) return x;
        throw new IllegalStateException(String.format("Cannot find node at index %s", index));
    }

    private Node<T> findLast() {
        for (Node<T> x = instance.first; x != null; x = x.next)
            if (x.next == null) return x;
        throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot find last node - malformed linked list");
    }
}
```

And here is the test suite:

```
public class CyclicLinkedListTest {

@Test
public void testListNoCycle() {
    CyclicLinkedList.AddNext<Integer> listBuilder = standardListBuilder();
    CyclicLinkedList<Integer> list = listBuilder.defineCycleOrBuild().build();
    assertEquals(Optional.empty(), list.firstNodeInCycle());
}

@Test
public void testListCycleAtBeginning() {
    CyclicLinkedList.AddNext<Integer> listBuilder = standardListBuilder();

    CyclicLinkedList<Integer> list = listBuilder
            .defineCycleOrBuild()
            .connectLastTo(4) // node index
            .build();

    assertEquals(Optional.of(10), list.firstNodeInCycle());
}

@Test
public void testListCycleInMiddle() {
    CyclicLinkedList.AddNext<Integer> listBuilder = standardListBuilder();

    CyclicLinkedList<Integer> list = listBuilder
            .defineCycleOrBuild()
            .connectLastTo(2) // node index
            .build();

    assertEquals(Optional.of(30), list.firstNodeInCycle());
}

@Test
public void testListCycleAtEnd() {
    CyclicLinkedList.AddNext<Integer> listBuilder = standardListBuilder();

    CyclicLinkedList<Integer> list = listBuilder
            .defineCycleOrBuild()
            .connectLastTo(0) // node index
            .build();

    assertEquals(Optional.of(50), list.firstNodeInCycle());
}

private static CyclicLinkedList.AddNext<Integer> standardListBuilder() {
    return CyclicLinkedList.<Integer>builder().addNext(50).addNext(40).addNext(30).addNext(20).addNext(10);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> ```
>     while (true) {
>         if (fast == null) return Optional.empty(); // if fast reaches end, no cycle
>         fast = fast.next; // advance fast one more step
>         if (fast == null) return Optional.empty(); // again check if fast reached end - if it does, no cycle
>         fast = fast.next; // advance both one step
>         slow = slow.next;
>         if (fast.index == slow.index) { // if fast and slow are equal, that can only mean fast has reached slow from behind, thus proving cycle
>             slow = first;
>             while (true) { // find the starting point of the cycle
>                 if (fast.index == slow.index) return Optional.of(slow.item);
>                 slow = slow.next;
>                 fast = fast.next;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

I'd write this differently.  Consider

```
    do {
        if (fast == null || fast.next == null) {
            // if fast reaches end, no cycle
            return Optional.empty();
        }

        // advance fast two steps and slow one step
        fast = fast.next.next;
        slow = slow.next;
    } while (fast.index != slow.index);

    // if fast and slow are equal,
    // that can only mean fast has reached slow from behind, thus proving cycle
    slow = first;
    // find the starting point of the cycle
    while (fast.index != slow.index) {
        slow = slow.next;
        fast = fast.next;
    }

    return Optional.of(slow.item);
```

This reduces the number of branches by moving the condition into the looping check.

This reduces the indent by separating testing for a cycle from finding the cycle.

I prefer checking both exit conditions in the same `if`.

I prefer to always use the block version of the `if`.

There is an error here.  We do `fast.index` before we check if `fast` is `null`.  This is in both this code and your original.  I believe that your code relies on there being an odd number of elements in the list.  You only test with five elements.  I expect that it would fail on an even number of elements, e.g. two.  Haven't tried it though.

Comment: Excellent suggestions and nicely spotted bug. I've also rewritten the code as you had suggested and added the `fast` null check on while loop exit - it is arguably a little bit harder to read but it *feels* more elegant; can't say which version is the more perfomant one, probably yours due to reduction in cyclomatic complexity. I especially like how we perform the check and search in two different stages. Aside from a full stochastic test harness, can you suggest some alternative testing strategy that may be useful?